# Group and count in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count

I know I've seen this before but I can't find anything now. I want to group a query by a certain column and be able to display how many are in each group. I got the first part down:

```
@line_items = @project.line_items.all(:group => "device_id")
```

This is for my line item index view, which is just a table displaying the line items. How do I make a column in that table for "count" now that the line items are grouped by device?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can do `count` on `line_items` which will return you an ordered hash of `device_id` and `count`.

```
@project.line_items.group(:device_id).count
```

Comment: This gives a warning: `DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#calculate with finder options is deprecated. Please build a scope and then call calculate on it instead. (called from C:in 'count':)`

Comment: @Chloe - Try this in Rails 4 to remove the warning: `@project.line_items.group(:device_id).count`

Answer (score 23):

hash of devise_id as key and associated records count

```
@project.line_items.group(:device_id).count
```

Answer (score 13):

I think you can try this as well.

```
@project.line_items.group(:device_id).pluck("device_id, count(device_id)")
```

^^ This gives array of arrays with elements 'device_id and count'

Answer (score 10):

Just add a `:select` option:

```
@line_items = @project.line_items.all(
  :group  => "device_id",
  :select => "device_id, COUNT(*) as count"
)
```

Then each `@line_item` will have a `count` attribute.

Comment: hrm, I put debug(@line_items) in my view, but I don't see any counts, so I don't think I'm understanding you. I think the output is exactly the same as without the select option.

Comment: The debug method won't show the count because it's not an ActiveRecord attribute, but there *is* a count attribute on each object. In any case, Chandra's solution is much better.

Answer (score 4):

something like

```
 User.all(:joins => :comments, :select => "users.*, count(comments.id) as comments_count", :group => "users.id")
```

might also work...

Answer (score 1):

After this commit:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a1c05dd8b9bd3623289d3aa73dda2943d620cc34

there's a new way to do the same thing:

```
@project.line_items.count(:group => LineItem.arel_table[:device_id])
```

Answer (score 1):

For only count **pluck** would be faster here rather than **group**

```
@project.line_items.pluck(:device_id).count


@project.line_items.pluck(:device_id).uniq.count
```

Comment: They will return completely different results for enumerated attributes. For example:

`customer_subscriptions.group(:status).count` will return:

`{1 => 6, 2 => 11, 3 => 136, 0 => 30}`

and `customer_subscriptions.pluck(:status).count` will just return `183`

Comment: true, how about uniq then? @project.line_items.pluck(:device_id).uniq.count