# How to group and then count records in the database to show in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im new in rails and ruby! 
I have a database with records about articles. Each article has the following fields:
- tittle
- author
- body

I would like to render in the `index` page a list of the count of ALL articles with the same "tittle" and the same "author". Example:

Database:

```
tittle: "dogs", author: "john", body: "dogs are nice",
tittle: "cats", author: "john", body: "cats are nice",
tittle: "dogs", author: "Lisa", body: "dogs are bad",
tittle: "dogs", author: "john", body: "dogs are nice",
tittle: "dogs", author: "john", body: "dogs are nice",
tittle: "dogs", author: "Lisa", body: "dogs are bad"
```

Now in my index page I would like to list in the occurrence desc order like this:

```
Articles:
  tittle  Author  how many times

- "dogs"  "john"      3 
- "dogs"  "Lisa"      2
- "cats"  "Lisa"      1
```

I was thinking about enumerable: `'group_by'` , or a query `Article.select([:id, :name])` ? however, I don't know how to apply it to my code.

Currently my controller looks like this:

```
  def index
    @articles = Article.order(created_at: :desc)
  end
```

I would really appreciate ideas or solutions on how to solve this as painless as possible and keep learning from this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
@articles = Article.group(:tittle, :author).count
```

It will return you a hash like:

```
{ [tittle, author] => count, ... }
```

And you can iterate it like so:

```
@articles.each do |(tittle, author), count|
  ...
end
```

Also `.order(created_at: :desc)` part is redundant and I guess you have typo in `tittle` column name. I would rename it

Ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022424/4950680

Comment: You could also iterate via `each do |(title, author), count|` and skip that next line.

Comment: @engineersmnky Good catch! Thanks

Comment: @MartinZinovsky you awesome! that seems to work. Can you add me in one more things please? the result now is : `{["dog", "John"]=>3}` how can I make it look nicer? I tried `.humanize` but that works on strings. any suggestion? and thanks I really appreciate your time and help!!!

Comment: @Noname What do you mean by nicer?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky hey! I mean instead of displaying ```{["dog", "John"]=>3}, {["cat", "Lisa"]=>1}``` with curly brackets and such, to displace it like this:
```"dog", "John" => 3
   "cat", "Lisa" => 1 
```
More understandable for the readers and also with a break like between each.